# Unable to locate button and href in Selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I am trying to locate some elements in Selenium and I have problem.
There are no normal elements like ID etc.

Issue no 1 --> should click to Continue button

```
<a _ngcontent-c3="" routerlink="cms" href="/cms">Continue</a>
```

Issue no 2 --> should click to Add button

```
<button _ngcontent-c11="" aria-label="Add user" class="action-btn add" type="button">
```

[Issue 2 html screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqS3J.png)

I tried using fidning elements by PartialLinkText, I tried to make my own CSS selector/xPath, but test case always fails...

One of unsuccessful solutions for Issue 1:

```
WebElement continueButton = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Continue"));
continueButton.click();
```

Any suggestions? 
Thanks.

Comment: can you post the error as well.

Comment: Hi, here are screenshots of errors:
Continue - Issue - https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVWkm.png
Add button - Issue - https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAfYq.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find button by class and i hope using this xpath your problem will be 
Here your possible xpath is `//a[@routerlink='cms'][text()='Continue']` and `//button[@aria-label='Add user']/i']`

WebElement Continue = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30))
                        .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@routerlink='cms'][text()='Continue']")));
                Continue.click();

```
            WebElement adduser = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30))
                    .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@aria-label='Add user']/i")));

            adduser.click();
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work, even if element is unique when I search through html:

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@class='action-btn add']"}

Comment: before click element wait few second then  try to click..I test your xpath its seems okay..You can paste this on your chrome console so that you can understand that it will able to find button $x("//button[@class='action-btn add']")

Comment: Added Thread.sleep(5000); before click but result is the same. Cant figure out what I am doing wrong. Is there better option for wait? Thread.sleep worked for me ok until now.

Comment: Hi, I tried both and I posted screenshots of errors in comment above: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVWkm.png,  https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAfYq.png

Comment: Please check it now.Its working for me perfectly 

     WebElement Continue = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30))
                            .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@routerlink='cms'][text()='Continue']")));
                    Continue.click();

                    WebElement adduser = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30))
                            .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@aria-label='Add user']/i")));

                    adduser.click();